# Android native map VS google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps

Is android's native map api (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) the same as google maps? Meaning, do I need an API key to use it? Do I need to follow the same terms of use as google?

If they are not the same, why would one choose one over the other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from Android support:

The Maps Terms of Service are here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

This is the TOS linked to from the Google Maps Android API page, here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

So yes, that TOS is the one that applies to maps on Android.

Hope that clears it up :)

---

Conclusion:
The TOS are the same as google maps.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Map is a kind of data structure, it is used for save & get data by key index.

google map is a wighet for develop app which need show maps.

They are completely different two things! You should choose the second one.

Comment: the native map api inside android doesn't show maps? Sorry if this sounded stupid. I am coming from an iOS world, and this android map thing new to me.

Comment: you may not know well with Java, the 'java.util.Map' in java like 'NSDictionary' in objective-c.